# Clear a zone outside a specific circle with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, view, porter-duff

I have a custom view which show a progress by filling a circle but now I'm looking for a way to erase the zone of my view **outside** this white circle :

[image]

Here, my code :

```
public class CircleGauge extends View {
    private int value = 75;
    private Paint backgroundPaint, gaugePaint, textPaint, circlePaint;

    ... constructors 

    private void init() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        backgroundPaint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.favorite_position_gauge_background, null));
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        gaugePaint = new Paint();
        gaugePaint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.favorite_position_gauge, null));
        gaugePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, metrics));
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        textPaint.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 23, metrics));
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), backgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, ((float) (100 - value) / 100F) * canvas.getHeight(), canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), gaugePaint);
        canvas.drawText(getContext().getString(R.string.percent_value, value), getWidth() / 2, getHeight() * .6F, textPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, (getHeight() / 2) - circlePaint.getStrokeWidth() / 2, circlePaint);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I pretty sure I can do this with [PorterDuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android drawable resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) already give you everything you need to make this without resorting to subclassing `View` and overriding `onDraw`.

First let's start with the drawable resource.  We want to have a circle with one color covering a circle of another color.  For this we use a `LayerDrawable` which is specified in XML with `<layer-list>`.

Each `Drawable` has a *level* value.  You can adjust the level (0-10000) by calling `setLevel` on the `Drawable`.  We want to use the level to control the appearance of the lighter circle. For that we will use a `ClipDrawable` which is defined in XML with `<clip>`.

For the circles themselves, we can use `ShapeDrawable`s (`<shape>`).  Here's what it looks like when we put it all together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/field" android:gravity="fill">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <solid android:color="#FF78606D"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/progress" android:gravity="fill">
        <clip android:gravity="bottom" android:clipOrientation="vertical">
            <shape android:shape="oval" >
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                <solid android:color="#FFAB9BA6"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Now we can just use a `TextView and put this drawable as the background.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_progress"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="0%"/>
```

Based on your colors I used `Theme.AppCompat` which is a dark theme.

Here's a quick and dirty demo that shows how it all works together:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        setLevel(0);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                        publishProgress(i);
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // just leave
                }

                return null;
            };

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                setLevel(values[0]);
            }
        }.execute();

    }

    private void setLevel(int level) {

        mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(level) + "%");
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) mTextView.getBackground();
        Drawable progress = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progress);
        progress.setLevel(level * 100); // drawable levels go 0-10000
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and it's elegant. I didn't know setLevel() method